# How to use Heatmap in angula6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am working on data visualization project in angular6. Can anyone help me to use heatmaps in the angular6 app? Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what library are you using? what type of data are you trying to integrate with a heatmap? what have you tired so far?

Comment: I am just searching for any relative library.

Answer (score 0):

In my past Project I used the NgxHeatMapModule. In the following link you can find the detailed guide to install the **ngx-heatmap** module which one you can use with angular6 pretty easily:
https://github.com/sanuradhag/ngx-heatmap

1. Install it through **`npm`**
2. Import the `NgxHeatMapModule`
3. And use the `<ngx-heatmap>` template.